# running incorrect docker image osx

Tags: docker

I created a new image running:

```
 docker build -t team1/es-image2 . | tee build.log
```

First, the create date doesn't reflect today's date. I wasn't concerned with that at first but after running it, it sort of makes sense...the running image is from another image created previously. I ran it with this command:

```
 docker run -i  -t --rm -P team1/es-image2
```

I verified that the correct image was running using:

```
 docker ps
```

I deleted the older image and tried running again but it still appears to be running the older image because -P showed all the older mapped ports and the working directory was also from the older image.

So, I can't understand why, the build is using the older containers even though the Dockerfile is not specifying all the items that were specified in the older image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
docker ps
```

is only to show container.

To show images you need to use

```
docker images
```

And to delete them use

```
docker rmi
```

A little clarification about image and container.
An image is the definition of a container, and a container is a part of the system isolated from the current directory tree.
You use an image to run a container. You can use the same image to run multiple container.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Regan. Yes, I used the images, rm & rmi commands.So then, I used a different dockerfile and created a new image...I thought this new image would create it's own containers and associate them to the new image so that when I run the image it is using the items specified in the dockerfile. It sounds like I need to do some manual configuration after building an image

Comment: You mean the new image created with a different Dockerfile created the same container?

Comment: yes. The 1st Dockerfile had nodejs, rabbitmq, eleasticsearch, erlang and a few other installs in it. The new dockerfile was scaled back to just have elastic, java & go. The WORKDIR was not set in the new file yet it defaulted to the old one. I cleaned out everything an will try re-building both dockerfiles again.

Comment: Also, the -P showed ports exposed from the old file. The new one only exposed 2 ports used by elastic. Thanks!

Comment: If problem persist can you edit your question to add the both Dockerfile and the step you followed to build and run them.

Comment: After deleting everything the new dockerfile build works as expected. I'm going to build the old one and try to run each one to see the outcome. @Regan

Comment: OK @Regan thanks! I'll do that tomorrow if things don't pan out. Either way, I'll post my results.

Answer (score 1):

When building the image from the Dockerfile, you may specify `--no-cache=true` to exclude any intermediate builds.

Comment: Thanks @jRadd. I use --rm to rid of intermediate containers. Will the no-cache help with my issue or just a performance tip?

Comment: It is actually for troubleshooting in this case. It would just force docker to re build from scratch, without using any cache.